# Check password length with regex

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I have a weird behavior for my with `regex` so I hope someone can explain it to me:

```
let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.*[A-Z]).(?=.*[0-9]).(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$")
```

I want my password to be **at least 8 characters**. But with the code above it is only allowing passwords **more than 8** characters. I used to thought that `{8,}` means `>=` and not `>`.

I know I can just change it to `{9,}` but I want to make sure that my logic is right, because if searching for this topic I always see that it means `>=`. So if anyone could just clarify that I'd be grateful :)

Comment: There are extraneous dots between lookaheads, remove them. The only consuming pattern should be `.{8,}`

Comment: that was the problem, thanks:)